# Taxonomy and Views - Creating a view based off of user selection

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

Been working with Drupal for a few weeks, and I have a question:

I have a large amount of content for content type X. I have built a view that returns certain fields from X nodes. Is there a way to build a user interface that will allow users to see all taxonomy tags for X and select a tag and then use that tag as a filter for the view?

For example, a user wants to see all results that are tagged "SEO." They will then see the views results for all nodes tagged with "SEO."

Comment: what version of views (2.x or 3.x) are you working with?

Comment: Views - 6.x-2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this; i'll offer up my easy answer.

You can show all of the nodes associated with a taxonomy tag by adding the "Taxonomy: Term" filter (select the taxonomy term ID filter). Select your relevant vocabulary, and then select 'dropdown' for your Selection Type.

Click 'Expose' to show a dropdown box to your users. When a user selects a tag from your dropdown, your results will be filtered according on the Operator you have chosen.

Comment: Thanks for helping out the new guy. I really appreciate your help.